# cypress runs all test files even when --spec parameter is used

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

I have two cypress test files, SmokeTest.spec.ts and ProfileTest.spec.ts. I want to run one file at a time in headless mode. I use the following command: `npm run cy:run --headless --spec cypress/integration/SmokeTest/SmokeTest.spec.ts`

Even though I'm using the --spec parameter, both test files run in headless mode.

I've also tried adding single quotes around the test file path like so: `--spec 'cypress/integration/SmokeTest/SmokeTest.spec.ts'` with the same results

Why would it run both tests?

Comment: I have added an answer to have a look, please try and let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cy:run` is a script entry in package.json which invokes `cypress run`.

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "cy:run": "cypress run"
```

To pass additional args to a script you must preceed them with `--` (note there are spaces before and after the double dash).

See [npm-run-script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script),

> The special option -- is used by getopt to delimit the end of the options. **npm will pass all the arguments after the -- directly to your script**

You don't need to add additional scripts to package.json.

It's also noted in the [Cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line.html#How-to-run-commands)

> When calling a command using npm run, you need to pass the command’s arguments using the -- string. For example, if you have the following command defined in your package.json

> {
> "scripts": {
> "cy:run": "cypress run"
> }
> }

> …and want to run tests from a single spec file and record the results on the Dashboard, the command should be:

> npm run cy:run -- --record --spec "cypress/integration/my-spec.js"

Your particular command line would be

```
npm run cy:run -- --headless --spec cypress/integration/SmokeTest/SmokeTest.spec.ts
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below command also to run a single spec file -

```
npx cypress run --spec "cypress/integration/SmokeTest/SmokeTest.spec.ts" --headless --browser chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please add the below under scripts in `package.json` file.

```
 "scripts": {
    "cy:smoketest-only": "cypress run --headless --spec cypress/integration/SmokeTest/SmokeTest.spec.ts --browser electron"
  }
```

or use global patterns:

```
 "scripts": {
        "cy:smoketest-only": "cypress run --headless --spec cypress/integration/SmokeTest/**/* --browser electron"
      }
```

and then run the below command from command prompt from the project root folder

```
npm run cy:smoketest-only
```

[image]